# LinkedIn API Error Unknown Field in resource Root

Tags: php, laravel, linkedin-api

Due to the May 2015 updates my application cannot use the login with LinkedIn option, this is the snippet I'm using:

```
$linkedinService->request('/people/~:(first-name,last-name,email-address)?format=json')
```

When I use the web console it returns the correct data, but if I dump the result from the app I get this:

```
array (size=5)
  'errorCode' => int 0
  'message' => string 'Unknown field {~%3A%28first-name%2Clast-name%2Cemail-address%29} in resource {Root}' (length=83)
  'requestId' => string 'asdfghjk' (length=10)
  'status' => int 400
  'timestamp' => int 1435742730817
```

Update:
The exact curl request is: (with access token)

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1//people/~%3A%28first-name%2Clast-name%2Cemail-address%29?format=json&oauth2_access_token=
```

If I paste that in the web console I get

```
Could not find person based on: ~%3A%28first-name%2Clast-name%2Cemail-address%29
```

But if I urldecode it first and paste it in it returns the correct data

Comment: The 0 error code usually means that no errors happened but the status 400 suggests that your request was bad.

Comment: Ok I'll try and get it to dump the exact curl request

Comment: There seems to be a similar problem here: https://github.com/logical-and/php-oauth/issues/46

Comment: Hoping that it will get fixed, GL HF

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the same problem. I find out that it is URL Problem. In request uri don't use `//` double slash like you did in your example `m/v1//people/`.

I know its been you have posted here but someone else can get benefit of it.